# Identifying whether Date in daylight saving or not in Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to identify if a date is in daylight saving time zone or not in mysql ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a date is in Daylight saving time in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013630/detect-if-a-date-is-in-daylight-saving-time-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store dates in MySQL using UTC times (which have no daylight savings). That way, you can be assured of standardization in the database, and you can handle timezones in the code reliably.

Comment: I am storing them in the DB as UTC, i just need a way to identify whether a date is in DST in my mysql query

Comment: accepting the closest answer, even though the answer is not completely convincing.