# check if datetime field is British Summer Time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in a select command to check if a datetime field is within the range of British Summer Time and, if so, add an hour onto the time?

If this isnt possible, can I do it in a stored procedure instead. So i would iterate over a temporary table where one of the columns is a date and if the date was BST then I could add an hour to the value of the date in the temporary table

thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a date is in Daylight saving time in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013630/detect-if-a-date-is-in-daylight-saving-time-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. `DATETIME` columns store just date and time, accurate to the second.

To include time zones, you need a `TIMESTAMP` column. `TIMESTAMP` values are stored as UTC so there's no conversion needed to handle BST or other time changes. There's more information [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed33/1).